# Can't get variable from Laravel ORM relations

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, orm

I want to get "$invoice->form->form" parameter here because i want to use it in view. When i am using dd($invoice->form); than gets null. Invoice and form are other tables and models but are connected with laravel relationship and foreign keys in migrations.

```
public function show(Invoice $invoice)
{
        dd($invoice->form);
    return view('invoices.show',compact('invoice'));
}
```

This is begining of invoice controller file:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Kyslik\ColumnSortable\Sortable;    
use App\Invoice;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Proform;
use App\Form;
use App\Currency;
use DB;
```

Here is invoice model

```
<?php


namespace App;

use Kyslik\ColumnSortable\Sortable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Invoice extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *  
     * @var array
     */
    use SoftDeletes;
    use Sortable;
    
    
    protected $table = 'invoices';

    
    protected $fillable = [
        'invoicenumber', 'invoicedate', 'id', 'selldate', 'user_id', 'paymentmethod', 
        'paymentdate', 'status', 'comments', 'city', 'paid',  'autonumber', 'automonth', 'autoyear', 'name',
         'PKWIU', 'quantity', 'unit', 'netunit', 'nettotal',
         'VATrate', 'grossunit', 'grosstotal', 'form_id', 'currency_id',
    ];
    
    public $sortable = [ 'invoicenumber', 'invoicedate', 'id', 'selldate', 'user_id', 'paymentmethod', 
        'paymentdate', 'status', 'comments', 'city', 'paid',  'autonumber', 'automonth', 'autoyear', 'name',
         'PKWIU', 'quantity', 'unit', 'netunit', 'nettotal',
         'VATrate', 'grossunit', 'grosstotal', 'form_id', 'currency_id',
                       ];
    
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    
        public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

        public function form()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Form');
    }

         public function currency()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Currency');
    }
   
        public function proform()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Proform');
    } 
    
}
```

Here is form model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Form extends Model
{
    //
    
        protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'form', 
    ];
    
        public function invoice()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Invoice');
    }  
    
    
    
        public function proform()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Proform');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you aren't loading the relation.

On your controller you should query like: `$invoice = Invoice::with('form')->find($invoice_id);` and return it to the view like: `return view('invoices.show', [ 'invoice' => $invoice->form ]);`

Comment: Thanks but get error: undefined variable $invoice_id

Comment: After change :
        $invoice = Invoice::with('form')->find(1);

        return view('invoices.show', [ 'invoice' => $invoice->form ]);
I've got Trying to get property 'form' of non-object